# Android - foreground Activity being killed when background system service scheduling restart by ActivityManager

Tags: android, service, android-activity, kill, foreground

I have a viewer application, implement with `ImageView` and `ViewPager` from Android Compatibility Package. For each page, I render some `Bitmap` and put them into `ViewPager`. It works fine, but sometimes the application just crashed without exception nor register dump. I noticed that, normally, the application didn't crash, just log many GC messages. But when system `ActivityManager` start to schedule restart some background system `Service`, the application get a big chance to crash when switching between pages.

I searched some questions, but they are about `Service` being killed because of low memory, restart failed because of state inconsistency, or something. But in my case, It's foreground `Activity` being killed, just because some system Services were scheduled restart. How could a foreground Activity being killed "by background Service"?

Although in log, the Services seem to restart failed because of low memory, but my Activity just being killed without OutOfMemoryError. I can't figure out what is the real problem caused my application being killed...

PS. If I don't switch between pages, the application lives, but system is scheduling restart Services repeatedly. In this situation, the application is easy to crash when switching between pages.

PS2. device is: ASUS Transformer TF101, Android 3.2, Kernel version: 2.6.36.3-00003-g9baf8f7

Here is the log, mycompany.viewer.MagazineActivity is the main Activity:

```
10-21 15:18:47.260: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Process com.google.android.apps.maps:NetworkLocationService (pid 14583) has died.
10-21 15:18:47.260: WARN/ActivityManager(135): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.location.internal.server.NetworkLocationService in 56367ms
10-21 15:18:47.260: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Low Memory: No more background processes.
10-21 15:18:47.360: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Process com.google.android.music (pid 14500) has died.
10-21 15:18:47.360: WARN/ActivityManager(135): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.music/.dl.DownloadManager$DownloadManagerService in 66267ms
10-21 15:18:47.360: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Low Memory: No more background processes.
10-21 15:18:47.560: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Process android.process.media (pid 14482) has died.
10-21 15:18:47.560: WARN/ActivityManager(135): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.android.providers.media/.MtpService in 76067ms
10-21 15:18:47.560: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Low Memory: No more background processes.
10-21 15:18:47.660: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Process net.smart.appstore.client (pid 14610) has died.
10-21 15:18:47.660: WARN/ActivityManager(135): Scheduling restart of crashed service net.smart.appstore.client/.service.LogSenderService in 85969ms
10-21 15:18:47.660: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Low Memory: No more background processes.
10-21 15:18:47.760: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Process com.asus.keyboard (pid 14617) has died.
10-21 15:18:47.760: WARN/ActivityManager(135): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.asus.keyboard/.KeyboardService in 95868ms
10-21 15:18:47.760: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Low Memory: No more background processes.
10-21 15:18:47.830: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Process com.asus.DLNA (pid 14634) has died.
10-21 15:18:47.830: WARN/ActivityManager(135): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.asus.DLNA/.MusicPlaybackService in 105803ms
10-21 15:18:47.830: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Low Memory: No more background processes.
10-21 15:18:48.230: DEBUG/dalvikvm(14526): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 431K, 31% free 19826K/28615K, paused 23ms
10-21 15:18:52.480: DEBUG/dalvikvm(14526): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1293K, 29% free 20566K/28615K, paused 2ms+3ms
10-21 15:18:52.840: DEBUG/skia(14526): purging 213K from font cache [14 entries]
10-21 15:18:52.870: DEBUG/dalvikvm(14526): GC_EXPLICIT freed 378K, 30% free 20189K/28615K, paused 2ms+3ms
10-21 15:18:53.640: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Start proc com.asus.DLNA for service com.asus.DLNA/com.asus.DMS.DLNAServerService: pid=14642 uid=10054 gids={3003, 1015}
10-21 15:18:53.690: INFO/DMS(14642):   ===========================>   onCreate()
10-21 15:18:54.040: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Process com.asus.DLNA (pid 14642) has died.
10-21 15:18:54.040: WARN/ActivityManager(135): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.asus.DLNA/com.asus.DMS.DLNAServerService in 137364ms
10-21 15:18:54.040: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Low Memory: No more background processes.
10-21 15:18:54.770: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Process com.google.process.gapps (pid 25767) has died.
10-21 15:18:54.770: WARN/ActivityManager(135): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gsf/.gtalkservice.service.GTalkService in 108858ms
10-21 15:18:54.770: WARN/ActivityManager(135): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.location/.NetworkLocationService in 118858ms
10-21 15:18:54.780: DEBUG/LocationProviderProxy(135): LocationProviderProxy.onServiceDisconnected ComponentInfo{com.google.android.location/com.google.android.location.NetworkLocationService}
10-21 15:18:54.780: DEBUG/GeocoderProxy(135): onServiceDisconnected ComponentInfo{com.google.android.location/com.google.android.location.NetworkLocationService}
10-21 15:18:54.780: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Low Memory: No more background processes.
10-21 15:18:55.430: ERROR/InputDispatcher(135): channel '4110db70 mycompany.viewer/mycompany.viewer.MagazineActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
10-21 15:18:55.430: ERROR/InputDispatcher(135): channel '4110db70 mycompany.viewer/mycompany.viewer.MagazineActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
10-21 15:18:55.430: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Process mycompany.viewer (pid 14526) has died.
10-21 15:18:55.440: INFO/WindowManager(135): WIN DEATH: Window{4110db70 mycompany.viewer/mycompany.viewer.MagazineActivity paused=false}
10-21 15:18:55.440: INFO/WindowManager(135): WINDOW DIED Window{4110db70 mycompany.viewer/mycompany.viewer.MagazineActivity paused=false}
10-21 15:18:55.470: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Start proc com.android.launcher for activity com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher: pid=14649 uid=10037 gids={}
10-21 15:18:55.470: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Low Memory: No more background processes.
10-21 15:18:55.660: DEBUG/dalvikvm(135): GC_EXPLICIT freed 875K, 22% free 26097K/33415K, paused 29ms+15ms
10-21 15:18:55.670: DEBUG/WindowManager(135): adjustConfigurationLw, config:{1.0 0mcc0mnc (no locale) sw800dp w1280dp h752dp xlrg land ?uimode ?night finger -keyb/v/h -nav/v} mLidOpen:-1 mHasDockFeature:true mHasHallSensorFeature:true config.hardKeyboardHidden:2
10-21 15:18:55.710: INFO/ActivityThread(14649): Pub com.android.launcher2.settings: com.android.launcher2.LauncherProvider
10-21 15:18:56.250: DEBUG/dalvikvm(14649): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 132K, 4% free 6513K/6727K, paused 34ms
10-21 15:18:56.350: DEBUG/dalvikvm(14649): GC_CONCURRENT freed 40K, 2% free 6953K/7047K, paused 2ms+2ms
10-21 15:18:56.870: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Start proc com.asus.mygazine for broadcast com.asus.mygazine/.UtilsReceiver: pid=14659 uid=10027 gids={1015}
10-21 15:18:56.910: DEBUG/TabletStatusBar(186): lights on
10-21 15:18:56.940: DEBUG/dalvikvm(14649): GC_CONCURRENT freed 197K, 4% free 7231K/7495K, paused 6ms+2ms
10-21 15:18:56.960: DEBUG/dalvikvm(87): GC_EXPLICIT freed 11K, 5% free 6298K/6595K, paused 3ms+2ms
10-21 15:18:56.980: DEBUG/libEGL(14649): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
10-21 15:18:57.000: DEBUG/dalvikvm(87): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 5% free 6298K/6595K, paused 2ms+2ms
10-21 15:18:57.030: DEBUG/dalvikvm(87): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 5% free 6298K/6595K, paused 2ms+3ms
10-21 15:18:57.060: DEBUG/libEGL(14649): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
10-21 15:18:57.160: DEBUG/libEGL(14649): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
10-21 15:18:57.190: DEBUG/libEGL(14649): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
10-21 15:18:57.240: DEBUG/OpenGLRenderer(14649): Creating OpenGL renderer caches
10-21 15:18:57.250: DEBUG/OpenGLRenderer(14649): Enabling debug mode 0
10-21 15:18:57.250: DEBUG/OpenGLRenderer(14649): Layers will be composited as regions
10-21 15:18:57.250: DEBUG/dalvikvm(14649): GC_CONCURRENT freed 252K, 5% free 7430K/7815K, paused 3ms+2ms
10-21 15:18:57.260: INFO/TextType(212): TextType = 0x0
10-21 15:18:57.260: WARN/InputManagerService(135): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 14526 uid 10065
```

PS3. some other log to describe the crash progress

After crash, those background services can start:

```
10-24 14:06:00.099: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Start proc com.asus.DLNA for service com.asus.DLNA/com.asus.DMS.DLNAServerService: pid=6482 uid=10054 gids={3003, 1015}
10-24 14:06:44.319: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Start proc com.android.bluetooth for service com.android.bluetooth/.pbap.BluetoothPbapService: pid=6495 uid=10061 gids={3003, 3002, 3001, 1015}
10-24 14:06:44.359: INFO/ActivityThread(6495): Pub com.android.bluetooth.opp: com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppProvider
10-24 14:07:04.319: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Start proc com.rechild.advancedtaskkiller for service com.rechild.advancedtaskkiller/.BackService: pid=6502 uid=10077 gids={1007, 3003, 1015}
10-24 14:07:14.849: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Start proc android.process.acore for content provider com.android.providers.contacts/.ContactsProvider2: pid=6512 uid=10009 gids={3003, 1015}
10-24 14:07:14.889: INFO/ActivityThread(6512): Pub user_dictionary: com.android.providers.userdictionary.UserDictionaryProvider
10-24 14:07:14.899: INFO/ActivityThread(6512): Pub com.android.social: com.android.providers.contacts.SocialProvider
10-24 14:07:14.919: INFO/ActivityThread(6512): Pub applications: com.android.providers.applications.ApplicationsProvider
10-24 14:07:14.949: INFO/ActivityThread(6512): Pub contacts;com.android.contacts: com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2
10-24 14:07:14.959: INFO/ActivityThread(6512): Pub call_log: com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider
```

Open the viewer again, load some pages, background services begin to die,

```
10-24 14:08:22.269: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Process android.process.media (pid 6422) has died.
10-24 14:08:22.329: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Process com.asus.mygazine (pid 6385) has died.
10-24 14:08:22.429: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Process com.google.android.apps.maps:FriendService (pid 6460) has died.
10-24 14:08:22.529: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Process android.process.acore (pid 6512) has died.
10-24 14:08:22.539: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Low Memory: No more background processes.
10-24 14:08:33.839: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Process com.android.launcher (pid 6375) has died.
10-24 14:08:33.839: INFO/WindowManager(135): WIN DEATH: Window{40e07160 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher paused=false}
10-24 14:08:33.839: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Low Memory: No more background processes.
```

and scheduling restart.

```
10-24 14:08:51.279: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Process com.google.android.music (pid 6398) has died.
10-24 14:08:51.279: WARN/ActivityManager(135): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.music/.dl.DownloadManager$DownloadManagerService in 5000ms
10-24 14:08:51.279: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Low Memory: No more background processes.
10-24 14:08:51.369: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Process com.google.android.apps.maps:NetworkLocationService (pid 6452) has died.
10-24 14:08:51.369: WARN/ActivityManager(135): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.location.internal.server.NetworkLocationService in 14904ms
10-24 14:08:51.369: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Low Memory: No more background processes.
10-24 14:08:51.469: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Process com.android.bluetooth (pid 6495) has died.
10-24 14:08:51.469: WARN/ActivityManager(135): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.android.bluetooth/.pbap.BluetoothPbapService in 24806ms
10-24 14:08:51.469: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Low Memory: No more background processes.
10-24 14:08:51.569: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Process com.asus.DLNA (pid 6482) has died.
10-24 14:08:51.569: WARN/ActivityManager(135): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.asus.DLNA/.MusicPlaybackService in 34707ms
10-24 14:08:51.569: WARN/ActivityManager(135): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.asus.DLNA/com.asus.DMS.DLNAServerService in 44707ms
10-24 14:08:51.569: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Low Memory: No more background processes.
10-24 14:08:51.669: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Process com.rechild.advancedtaskkiller (pid 6502) has died.
10-24 14:08:51.669: WARN/ActivityManager(135): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.rechild.advancedtaskkiller/.BackService in 54607ms
10-24 14:08:51.669: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Low Memory: No more background processes.
10-24 14:08:56.299: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Start proc com.google.android.music for service com.google.android.music/.dl.DownloadManager$DownloadManagerService: pid=6528 uid=10029 gids={3003, 1015}
10-24 14:08:56.409: INFO/ActivityThread(6528): Pub com.google.android.music.MusicContent: com.google.android.music.store.MusicContentProvider
10-24 14:08:56.439: INFO/MusicStore(6528): Database version: 31
10-24 14:08:56.439: WARN/AndroidMusic(6528): Need to wait for MusicPreferences to be created
10-24 14:08:56.639: WARN/AndroidMusic(6528): MusicPreferences still not made, creating on UI thread
```

Sometimes, some of them would start successfully.

```
10-24 14:09:16.299: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Start proc com.android.bluetooth for service com.android.bluetooth/.pbap.BluetoothPbapService: pid=6580 uid=10061 gids={3003, 3002, 3001, 1015}
10-24 14:09:16.329: INFO/ActivityThread(6580): Pub com.android.bluetooth.opp: com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppProvider
10-24 14:09:26.309: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Start proc com.asus.DLNA for service com.asus.DLNA/.MusicPlaybackService: pid=6588 uid=10054 gids={3003, 1015}
10-24 14:09:36.289: INFO/DMS(6588):   ===========================>   onCreate()
10-24 14:09:46.299: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Start proc com.rechild.advancedtaskkiller for service com.rechild.advancedtaskkiller/.BackService: pid=6595 uid=10077 gids={1007, 3003, 1015}
10-24 14:09:56.299: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Start proc com.google.android.music for service com.google.android.music/.dl.DownloadManager$DownloadManagerService: pid=6602 uid=10029 gids={3003, 1015}
10-24 14:09:56.419: INFO/ActivityThread(6602): Pub com.google.android.music.MusicContent: com.google.android.music.store.MusicContentProvider
10-24 14:09:56.439: DEBUG/dalvikvm(6602): GC_CONCURRENT freed 165K, 4% free 6637K/6855K, paused 2ms+2ms
10-24 14:09:56.449: INFO/MusicStore(6602): Database version: 31
10-24 14:09:56.459: WARN/AndroidMusic(6602): Need to wait for MusicPreferences to be created
10-24 14:09:56.659: WARN/AndroidMusic(6602): MusicPreferences still not made, creating on UI thread
10-24 14:09:56.699: DEBUG/MusicPreferences(6602): New Active account: null
10-24 14:09:56.709: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Start proc android.process.media for content provider com.android.providers.media/.MediaProvider: pid=6616 uid=10031 gids={1015, 1023, 1024, 2001, 3003}
10-24 14:09:56.719: DEBUG/MusicStore(6602): Disabled WAL
10-24 14:09:56.719: DEBUG/MusicStore(6602): Database opened
10-24 14:09:56.739: INFO/ActivityThread(6616): Pub media: com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider
10-24 14:09:56.739: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Process com.google.android.apps.maps:NetworkLocationService (pid 6558) has died.
10-24 14:09:56.749: WARN/ActivityManager(135): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.location.internal.server.NetworkLocationService in 5000ms
10-24 14:09:56.749: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Low Memory: No more background processes.
10-24 14:09:57.099: INFO/MediaProvider(6616): Update ID=1, mount=/system, isMounted=1, VID = -1
10-24 14:09:57.139: INFO/MediaProvider(6616): Update ID=2, mount=/data, isMounted=1, VID = -1
10-24 14:09:57.509: INFO/MediaProvider(6616): Update ID=1, mount=/mnt/sdcard, isMounted=1, VID = -1
10-24 14:09:57.529: INFO/ActivityThread(6616): Pub downloads: com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider
10-24 14:09:57.539: INFO/ActivityThread(6616): Pub drm: com.android.providers.drm.DrmProvider
```

Then the system begins to scheduling restart, success some, failed some, repeatedly. Btw, `com.google.android.music/.dl.DownloadManager$DownloadManagerService` and `com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.location.internal.server.NetworkLocationService` always failed to restart.

Log looks like mix of "Scheduling restart...", "Start proc...", "GC ..."

If I switch between pages, more Services are killed, system still scheduling restart repeatedly.

```
10-24 14:11:04.619: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Process com.android.bluetooth (pid 6763) has died.
10-24 14:11:04.619: WARN/ActivityManager(135): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.android.bluetooth/.pbap.BluetoothPbapService in 77800ms
10-24 14:11:04.619: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Low Memory: No more background processes.
10-24 14:11:04.729: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Process com.asus.DLNA (pid 6588) has died.
10-24 14:11:04.729: WARN/ActivityManager(135): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.asus.DLNA/com.asus.DMS.DLNAServerService in 22273ms
10-24 14:11:04.729: WARN/ActivityManager(135): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.asus.DLNA/.MusicPlaybackService in 32273ms
10-24 14:11:04.729: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Low Memory: No more background processes.
10-24 14:11:04.849: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Process com.rechild.advancedtaskkiller (pid 6595) has died.
10-24 14:11:04.849: WARN/ActivityManager(135): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.rechild.advancedtaskkiller/.BackService in 42147ms
10-24 14:11:04.849: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Low Memory: No more background processes.
10-24 14:11:05.959: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Process com.google.process.gapps (pid 6410) has died.
10-24 14:11:05.959: WARN/ActivityManager(135): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gsf/.gtalkservice.service.GTalkService in 51042ms
10-24 14:11:05.959: DEBUG/LocationProviderProxy(135): LocationProviderProxy.onServiceDisconnected ComponentInfo{com.google.android.location/com.google.android.location.NetworkLocationService}
10-24 14:11:05.959: DEBUG/GeocoderProxy(135): onServiceDisconnected ComponentInfo{com.google.android.location/com.google.android.location.NetworkLocationService}
10-24 14:11:05.959: WARN/ActivityManager(135): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.location/.NetworkLocationService in 61042ms
10-24 14:11:05.959: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Low Memory: No more background processes.
10-24 14:11:06.079: DEBUG/dalvikvm(6438): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 431K, 27% free 21267K/28871K, paused 23ms
10-24 14:11:07.009: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Start proc com.google.android.music for service com.google.android.music/.dl.DownloadManager$DownloadManagerService: pid=6771 uid=10029 gids={3003, 1015}
10-24 14:11:07.129: INFO/ActivityThread(6771): Pub com.google.android.music.MusicContent: com.google.android.music.store.MusicContentProvider
10-24 14:11:07.149: DEBUG/dalvikvm(6771): GC_CONCURRENT freed 145K, 2% free 6739K/6855K, paused 8ms+2ms
10-24 14:11:07.149: INFO/MusicStore(6771): Database version: 31
10-24 14:11:07.159: WARN/AndroidMusic(6771): Need to wait for MusicPreferences to be created
10-24 14:11:07.229: DEBUG/dalvikvm(6438): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1293K, 24% free 22006K/28871K, paused 2ms+4ms
10-24 14:11:07.359: WARN/AndroidMusic(6771): MusicPreferences still not made, creating on UI thread
10-24 14:11:07.369: INFO/ActivityManager(135): Start proc com.google.process.gapps for content provider com.google.android.gsf/.gservices.GservicesProvider: pid=6783 uid=10025 gids={3003, 1015, 2001, 1007}
10-24 14:11:07.419: INFO/ActivityThread(6783): Pub com.google.settings: com.google.android.gsf.settings.GoogleSettingsProvider
10-24 14:11:07.419: INFO/ActivityThread(6783): Pub subscribedfeeds: com.google.android.gsf.subscribedfeeds.SubscribedFeedsProvider
10-24 14:11:07.439: INFO/ActivityThread(6783): Pub com.google.contacts.gal.provider: com.google.android.syncadapters.contacts.GalProvider
10-24 14:11:07.449: INFO/ActivityThread(6783): Pub com.google.android.gsf.gservices: com.google.android.gsf.gservices.GservicesProvider
10-24 14:11:07.449: INFO/GservicesProvider(6783): Gservices pushing to system: true; secure: true
10-24 14:11:07.449: INFO/ActivityThread(6783): Pub com.google.android.providers.talk: com.google.android.gsf.talk.TalkProvider
```

Switching some more pages, finally, the application crashed, as the top most log.